# VBA nested For Each loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that is used to schedule the next upcoming task on a job. each row has 28 cells, each cell represents a day of the week within the 4 weeks lookahead. I made a formula to check the date of the cell with the start and end date of the task and fill the cell accordingly.

Here is the formula:

```
 =IFERROR(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Delivery",$D16)),VALUE(F$10)=VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AO53)),"D",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Calculation
 New'!$BH$13,$AJ16)),VALUE(F$10)>=VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AO53),VALUE(F$10)<=VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AP53)),"N",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Calculation
 New'!$BH$12,$AJ16)),VALUE(F$10)>=VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AO53),VALUE(F$10)<=VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AP53)),"E",IF(AND(VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AO53)=VALUE('Calculation New'!$AP53),F$10='Calculation
 New'!$AO53,NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Calculation
 New'!$BH$9,$D16)))),"SF",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Calculation
 New'!$BH$9,$D16)),VALUE(F$10)>=VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AO53),VALUE(F$10)<=VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AP53)),"I",IF(AND(VALUE(F$10)>VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AO53),VALUE(F$10)<VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AP53)),"X",IF(VALUE(F$10)=VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AO53),"S",IF(VALUE(F$10)=VALUE('Calculation
 New'!$AP53),"F","")))))))),"")
```

a few things to that formula:
D16:D85 on the sheet "SIS" is the Task description where to look for certain words
BH9 on sheet "Calculation New" contains a word to compare to. The range of words is BH3:BH13
F10:AF10 on the sheet "SIS" contains the date for the cells below of the day of the week
AO53:AO122 on sheet "Calculation New" contains the start date of a task
AP53:AP122 on sheet "Calculation New" contains the End date of a task

currently, I got 70 Rows times 28 cells and each cell has this formula in it. Now I want to rather use a VBA code do the same thing, but I am having a hard time to get started. I am not very experienced with VBA. I researched in regards to nesting For each loop but so far I am not succeeding.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you in advance
Dan

here is the code I have written so far not complete but I am stuck and need some advice

```
        Option Explicit
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

`Dim SDate As Range
Dim EDate As Range
Dim WDate As Range

Set SDate = Worksheets("Calculation New").Range("SDate")
Set EDate = Worksheets("Calculation New").Range("EDate")
Set WDate = Worksheets("Calculation New").Range("WDate")

    For SDate = 1 To Worksheets("Calculation New").Range("SDate").End(xlDown) 'lenght of range varies

       'For WDate = 1 To 28     ' length is always same
           'If cell = WDate Then 'i want to compare each cell of WDate with the start date
             'cell = "X"             

       'Next
   Next
End Sub`

Comment: Have you anything at all tried? People won't just write code for you - they will help you with what you have though

Comment: Hi Jeremy, yes I tried myself on writing the code but nothing I have tried worked. I have been searching the web for a week and found a few good explanations on how to use the for each loop but I can't seem to implement those samples to work for me. I understand that people don't have the time just to write code for others. Also, I don't expect them to. I just don't know what else to do in this regard. that's why I hoped the more experienced people could lend me a hand. Thank you for correcting my inital question.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started with VBA, you might want to start here. There's a lot of questionable sites offering VBA code but this is directly from Microsoft and covers the basics. Happy coding!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office

Comment: Hi Scipt Wolf, I did started coding with the for each loop but I got no luck. I don't grasp the concept fully on how to implement the various ranges. The formula is working fine and in that sense I understand what I want to accomplish but my lack of any vba knowledge doesn't help me. I will check out the link you have provided. I did also did research on my issue for the last week on various web sites and YouTube. I best learn when I see example code that I know what it does to understand the concept. But most sites have only very simple versions that I am stuck to improve to my needs. Thanks

Comment: I do also appreciate your quick response and understand that people don't just want to write codes for others. I would like to learn it myself to able to understand and write vba code. Once I have seen how I'll get it and can build on it. Thank you again for you time and help.

Answer (score 0):

For loops can be tricky - generally you can start with an array saying `r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange` and loop through it

```
Sub nestedLoop()
  r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  For i = LBound(r) To UBound(r)
    For j = LBound(r, 2) To UBound(r, 2)
      'evaluate r(i,j) do something
      'Debug.print r(i,j)
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Clyde, thank you very much for your sample I'll try it out and see if I can make it work. In general, I understand what a for each loop does but the syntax is what I am not familiar with. thank you Dan

Comment: sure thing :) glad to help good luck let me know how it goes for sure

Comment: A quick note: Using `ActiveSheet` is generally discouraged, as it can generate unexpected results (active referring to the currently selected sheet - the visible one). It's better to use either `Worksheets("name")` or the code name - defaults: Sheet1, Sheet2, etc. - these can be found in the project-folder list in the developers tab, usually on the left for me.)

Comment: something also worth noting - in the usedrange values, the first dimension of the r array is your rows and the second dimension will be the columns so this loop is gonna say for each row then for each column in the used range

Comment: Thank you both for your tips. Much appreciated.